# Automation of JSP scriptlets to JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, web, automation, jstl

**Situation:** A JEE project almost a decade old has over 5000 JSP files. The implementation had been using JSP scriptlets all over. It follows basic programming patterns and few homegrown utility classes to achieve the HTML UI rendering.

**Objective:** Increase the maintainability, improve the architecture and health of application by migrating all existing JSPs to use JSTL (and a few custom tag libraries). Also to develop future JSPs using tag libraries.

**Discussion point:** While developing custom tag libraries to cover for utility classes and using them along with JSTL for future JSPs is not a problem, manual migration of existing JSPs could take ages (including testing). **I am looking for a solution to automate the process.**

I was trying to explore if Tomcat Jasper engine's JSP parsing capabilities could be harnessed i.e. if it provides APIs to hook into their parsing process and receive scriptlets (& other contents) as events so I could implement desired conversion through it and stream out converted jsps. However, I have not found enough information online on this.

Please note that writing a parser using ANTLR or any other similar tool will be a bigger academic exercise and a project in its own right. Funding for this will not be approved.

Any pointer towards this solution or any other solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Been there, done that (or a similar thing), few times, and if I may give an advice, it would be: **drop the old crap and start from the scratch** using some modern approach (e.g. WebServices + React SPA). According to my experience, you don't have to re-implement it 1:1, those decade old legacy apps have like 50% of features no more in use (created for some power-user who used it once and then left the company), so a good analysis of what is actually used and what not could spare you a lot of time.

Comment: How I wish I could start afresh. This application is complicated, intensely used but only by a few 100 users. Business is happy using it as it is and paying little maintenance expense (with few enhancements) every year. Sadly bigger funding is not going to come through.

Comment: pity one can't react with an animated GIF here on SO. This is worth at least a "sad face", or even Gandalf saying "Fly, you fools!". :-/